# filter inside liveware in v3 - how to get filter state in filament?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have designed a filter inside liveware in filament-v2 and i was getting the state also inside `getTableQuery()` by using `getTableFilters` function (provided below).

```
$month_selected = $this-\>getTableFilterState("attendance_month")["value"];
```

But after upgrading to v3 I am not getting filter state. To check I have provided some customized code like below inside filters of table in liveware.

```
SelectFilter::make('attendance_month')->options([
  'January' => 'January',
  'February' => 'February',
  'March' => 'March',
  ]),
```

And then inside getTablequery function i have provide below code:

```
$month_selected = $this->table->getFilters();
```

After it when I tried to check `dump($month_selected);` I am getting below result instead of specific option which I have choosen.

```
"attendance_month" => Filament\Tables\Filters\SelectFilter {#3379 ▶}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the text is readable and the code is in code blocks.

Comment: ok sure 
Actually
i am trying to get the filter value inside getTableQuery(): Builder, which is inside a widget and extends TableWidget .so i am trying to fetch the filter value by using             $this->tableFilters['month']['value']                then initially i am getting null instead of default date .
then if i am selecting any other month then i am getting value of previous selected one . 

how to fix the issue and get the filter value of current selected value rather than previous selected value ,
 please guide me .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the table filters using

```
$filters = $this->getTable()->getFilters()
```

Or as mentioned in question you can also get filters Using:

```
$this->table->getFilters()
```

Then **if you want to access the value of a certain filter** you can use

```
$filters['filter_name']->getState()
```